# Configure custom SSLPolicy for v2 load balancer with cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

how would one configure a custom SSL Policy for a V2 application load balancer via cloudformation?

This post describes a policy configured via CLI: [AWS Cloudformation: Loadbalancer Custom SSL Negotiation Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757430/aws-cloudformation-loadbalancer-custom-ssl-negotiation-policy) but wondering how to customize this on a listener.

SslPolicy in the docs is a type String - is this a reference to a security policy resource object? Or a string of ciphers to enable? I don't want to use a predefined policy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy on ALB is a string because only the pre-defined, named policies are supported.

> Application Load Balancers do not support custom security policies.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#describe-ssl-policies

The available canned policies for ALB are also documented at the link, above.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I found the above link eventually. I have added a case in AWS Support, they've had a lot of requests for custom policies, and have associated my ticket with the feature request - so hopefully we get it some time. I've also asked them to create a predefined FS policy that has TLS1.0 disabled.

Comment: @Brett did they make the custom policy for you?